Q-learning model instable for a specific application
Assume we have this implementation of transport security Q-learning model
import numpy
import pandas

# Generate synthetic dataset
def generate_dataset(n_samples=1000):
    data = []
    for _ in range(n_samples):
        node = numpy.random.randint(0, 5)  # Random node between 0 and 4
        radiation_level = numpy.random.uniform(0.3, 0.7)
        traffic_level = numpy.random.uniform(0.1, 0.9)
        weather_condition = numpy.random.uniform(0.2, 0.8)
        security_status = numpy.random.choice([0, 1])
        humidity_level = numpy.random.uniform(0.3, 0.7)
        vehicle_speed = numpy.random.uniform(40, 100)
        macro_factor = numpy.random.uniform(0.4, 0.6)
        threat_level = 0.2 * radiation_level + 0.3 * traffic_level + 0.1 * weather_condition + 0.4 * (1 - security_status)
        data.append([node, radiation_level, traffic_level, weather_condition, security_status,
                     humidity_level, vehicle_speed, macro_factor, threat_level])
    columns = ['node', 'radiation_level', 'traffic_level', 'weather_condition', 'security_status',
               'humidity_level', 'vehicle_speed', 'macro_factor', 'threat_level']
    return pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

dataset = generate_dataset()

print(dataset)

import matplotlib.pyplot

class TransportSecurityEnv:
    def __init__(self, graph, goal_node, dataset):
        self.graph = graph
        self.goal_node = goal_node
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.actions = ["proceed", "reroute", "security", "emergency", "macro", "cyber"]
        self.reset()
        
    def reset(self):
        self.current_node = 0
        self.current_state = self.get_state(self.current_node)
        return self.current_state
    
    def step(self, action):
        action_name = self.actions[action]
        next_node = self.current_node
        
        if action_name == "proceed":
            next_node = self.graph[self.current_node][0]
        elif action_name == "reroute":
            next_node = self.graph[self.current_node][1] if len(self.graph[self.current_node]) > 1 else self.current_node
        
        self.current_node = next_node
        self.current_state = self.get_state(next_node)
        reward = self.compute_reward(self.current_state, action_name)
        done = next_node == self.goal_node
        return self.current_state, reward, done
    
    def get_state_space(self):
        return len(self.graph)
    
    def get_action_space(self):
        return len(self.actions)
    
    def get_state(self, node):
        # Sample a state from the dataset for the given node
        state_sample = self.dataset[self.dataset['node'] == node].sample(1).iloc[0]
        return state_sample.to_list()
    
    def compute_reward(self, state, action_name):
        N, R_N, T_N, W_N, S_N, H_N, V, F_macro, F_threat = state
        correct_action = self.select_correct_action(F_threat)
        
        R_security = 4 if S_N == 0 else 0
        R_efficiency = 4 if V >= 60 else 0 # 60 km/h as target speed
        R_safety = 4 if R_N <= 0.5 else 0  # Example radiation safety level
        R_risk = 4 if F_threat < 0.5 else 0  # Example threat level threshold
        R_macro = 4 if F_macro >= 0.5 else 0  # Example macro factor target
        
        reward = R_security + R_efficiency + R_safety + R_risk + R_macro
        
        if action_name == correct_action:
            reward += 10  # Bonus for correct action
        else:
            reward -= 0  # Penalty for incorrect action
        
        return reward
    
    def select_correct_action(self, threat_level):
        if threat_level >= 0.7:
            return "emergency"
        elif threat_level >= 0.5:
            return "security"
        elif threat_level >= 0.3:
            return "reroute"
        else:
            return "proceed"

def epsilon_greedy_policy(Q, state_index, epsilon, n_actions):
    if numpy.random.rand() < epsilon:
        return numpy.random.randint(n_actions)
    else:
        return numpy.argmax(Q[state_index])

def state_to_index(state):
    return int(state[0])

def q_learning(env, alpha=0.05, gamma=0.99, epsilon=1.0, epsilon_decay=0.995, epsilon_min=0.01, episodes=3000, convergence_threshold=1e-3, min_converged_episodes=20):
    n_states = env.get_state_space()
    n_actions = env.get_action_space()
    Q = numpy.random.rand(n_states, n_actions) * 0.01  # Small random values for Q initialization
    episode_rewards = []
    episode_lengths = []
    episode_losses = []
    action_counts = numpy.zeros((n_actions, episodes))
    converged_episodes = 0
    
    for episode in range(episodes):
        state = env.reset()
        state_index = state_to_index(state)
        total_reward = 0
        steps = 0
        delta = 0
        
        while True:
            action = epsilon_greedy_policy(Q, state_index, epsilon, n_actions)
            next_state, reward, done = env.step(action)
            next_state_index = state_to_index(next_state)
            
            best_next_action = numpy.argmax(Q[next_state_index])
            td_target = reward + gamma * Q[next_state_index, best_next_action]
            td_delta = td_target - Q[state_index, action]
            Q[state_index, action] += alpha * td_delta
            delta = max(delta, numpy.abs(td_delta))
            
            state_index = next_state_index
            total_reward += reward
            steps += 1
            action_counts[action, episode] += 1
            
            if done:
                break
        
        episode_rewards.append(total_reward)
        episode_lengths.append(steps)
        episode_losses.append(delta)
        
        if delta < convergence_threshold:
            converged_episodes += 1
            if converged_episodes >= min_converged_episodes:
                print(f"Converged after {episode+1} episodes.")
                break
        else:
            converged_episodes = 0
        
        # Decay epsilon to reduce exploration over time
        epsilon = max(epsilon * epsilon_decay, epsilon_min)
        
        if episode % 100 == 0:
            print(f"Episode {episode}/{episodes}")

    return Q, episode_rewards, episode_lengths, episode_losses, action_counts

def plot_results(episode_rewards, episode_lengths, episode_losses, action_counts):
    fig, axs = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(3, figsize=(12, 12))
    
    # Plot episode rewards
    axs[0].plot(episode_rewards)
    axs[0].set_title('Episode Rewards Over Time')
    axs[0].set_xlabel('Episode')
    axs[0].set_ylabel('Total Reward')
    
    # Plot episode lengths
    axs[1].plot(episode_lengths)
    axs[1].set_title('Episode Lengths Over Time')
    axs[1].set_xlabel('Episode')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('Number of Steps')
    
    # Plot episode losses
    axs[2].plot(episode_losses)
    axs[2].set_title('Loss Per Episode Over Time')
    axs[2].set_xlabel('Episode')
    axs[2].set_ylabel('Loss')
    
    matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout()
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()
    
    # Plot separate histograms for action counts
    for action in range(action_counts.shape[0]):
        matplotlib.pyplot.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
        matplotlib.pyplot.hist(action_counts[action], bins=range(0, 3000, 100), alpha=0.75, label=f'Action {action}')
        matplotlib.pyplot.title(f'Action {action} Counts Over Episodes')
        matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel('Episode')
        matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel('Count')
        matplotlib.pyplot.legend()
        matplotlib.pyplot.show()

# Define the graph representing the transportation network in Ukraine
graph = {
    0: [1, 0],
    1: [2, 1, 0],
    2: [3, 2, 1],
    3: [4, 3, 2],
    4: [4, 3]  # Goal node
}

# Main code
env = TransportSecurityEnv(graph, goal_node=4, dataset=dataset)
Q, episode_rewards, episode_lengths, episode_losses, action_counts = q_learning(
    env, alpha=0.1, gamma=-0.99, epsilon=0, epsilon_decay=0.995, epsilon_min=0.01, episodes=100)

plot_results(episode_rewards, episode_lengths, episode_losses, action_counts)

I need to understand the reasons why the model convergence is unstable.
As well as possible adjustments ( parameters tunning, model logic ).
